# SQL query for same user with last date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with following data. ID, date and type are all primary key. 
ID is person, type is for work type.

```
id     date     Type
--------------------------
6   |  2011   |  2
6   |  2012   |  2
6   |  2012   |  3
6   |  2012   |  5
7   |  2013   |  1
7   |  2016   |  1
etc..
```

I want to create a query that would show both id 6 that have difference type, and take the last date if there is tow row for same ID with same type.
The result should show same as that.

```
id     date     Type
--------------------------
6   |  2012   |  2
6   |  2012   |  3
6   |  2012   |  5
7   |  2016   |  1
etc..
```

Comment: There's more than one way to skin this cat, but which ways have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.type = t.type);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't show persons that have 3 difference type work, only show tow type work.

I have updated my topic.

Comment: Worked, just needed to add (where t2.id = t.id and t2.type = t.type)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it :

```
select a.id, b.date, a.type
 from 
(
    select distinct id, type 
    From Test1 
) a
INNER JOIN 
(
    select distinct id, max(date) date
    From Test1 
    group by id
) b 
on a.id = b.id
```